# Show parent taxonomy in custom post type

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have a set of schools in a custom post type with locations ordered as follows:

```
London
- 1 Oxford Road
- 2 Cambridge Road

Paris
- 1 Napoleon Road
- 2 Tower Road
```

How do I change the following so that the location parent is outputted instead of the location child:

```
// begin loop
$args = array('post_type' => 'school');
query_posts($args); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

// variable for location
$location = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', '', ', ', '' );

// output   
echo get_the_title() . ' - ' . $location;


// end loop
endwhile; endif;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't test the following script, but I hope it will bring you a step forward to the solution.

```
// begin loop
$args = array('post_type' => 'school');
query_posts($args); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

// variable for location
$term_list = '';
$terms     = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'location' );
$prefix    = '';

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, 'location' );
    $term_list  .= $prefix . $parent_term->name . ' - ' . $term->name;
    $prefix      = ', ';
}

// output
echo get_the_title() . ' - ' . $term_list;

// end loop
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: After 2 days of search, I found this... Thank you. I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'work_categories' to your taxonomy name - the code below is tested but won't work on the older PHP versions such 5.3.

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
$first_term_name = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'work_categories' )[0]->name;
var_dump( $first_term_name );
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
```