# Get all parent taxonomies of a WordPress post type

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361695/show-parent-taxonomy-in-custom-post-type) and used the technique myself but don't know where do  I go wrong, so let's look at the code.

Purpose: To get a list of all parent taxonomies in an option set for a select field

```
<option value="parent-cat-1">Parent Category 1</option>
<option value="parent-cat-2">Parent Category 2</option>
<option value="parent-cat-3">Parent Category 3</option>
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
      $taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies( $atts['post_type']);

     $args = array('post_type' => $atts['post_type']);
       query_posts($args); 
foreach ($taxonomy_names as $taxonomy_name) {
           if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       $terms     = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_name );

        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy_name );
            $term_list  .= $parent_term->name . ', ' ;

            }  
           var_dump($terms);
               endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
               echo $term_list;
}
```

`var_dump($terms);` shows `string(2) ", " string(4) ", , " string(18) ", , Category 1, , "`

```
var_dump($parent_term); shows object(WP_Error)#980 (2) { ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=> array(1) { ["invalid_term"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Empty Term" } } ["error_data":"WP_Error":private]=> array(0) { } } object(WP_Error)#1924 (2) { ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=> array(1) { ["invalid_term"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Empty Term" } } ["error_data":"WP_Error":private]=> array(0) { } } object(WP_Error)#1924 (2) { ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=> array(1) { ["invalid_term"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Empty Term" } } ["error_data":"WP_Error":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

I would consider wrapping all this stuff in a function, better.

Thanks

Comment: What does is container in $terms when you dump it?

Comment: @cjquinn , I updated the question, var_dump($terms); shows bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) .. Thanks

Comment: I see `$taxonomy_name` but never see it initiated... there is `$taxonomy_names` but its not used later.... can you check it?

Comment: @Seti , I just updated the question. What I want is, there are some other parent categories too, but they are not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select class="input-form"  size="1" name="what" required>
<option disabled selected>Выбрать</option>
<?php
$taxonomies  = get_taxonomies(array(
'object_type' => ['advert']
), 'objects');
foreach( $taxonomies as $cur_term ){
echo '<option value="' . $cur_term -> name . '">' . $cur_term -> label . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```